# Getting number of emails sent by specific user on Postfix

Tags: postfix

I run an SMTP server using Postfix. I want to be able to keep track of the amount of emails sent since forever by a specific SMTP user.

Seems easy enough, but how can I achieve this?

Comment: Use the log files or bcc another address for this user and then a program can count it. Or write a milter.

Comment: Also, you can only go back as far as your mail log files go, so if your system runs longer then the log rotation, everything before that is lost.

Answer (score 1):

There are some possibilities differing in complexity:

- Use log files and search them. There are again multiple possibilities do so.

  - You can use tools like logcheck which perform a egrep-based search on newly added lines
  - With logrotate you can execute commands after rotation, you can use this to run your counter
  - You can use features of syslog
- You can add a bcc for all mails addressed to a user and then programmatically count the amount of emails in this extra mailbox
- You can write a postfix milter, which either takes all email and counts those to be delivered to the special address, or let postfix filter them beforehand.

You can only look into the past with the log files, but only as far as you still have the files.

As you haven't given any more contraints, the answer is very broad. If you need details on the implementation, stackoverflow is probably a better place then serverfault.